# ESP32: **ERROR*** A stack overflow in task IDLE1 has been detected

Tags: esp32

I have hundreds of ESP32-based custom PCBs out there at customers locations.

It is the third time I get the product back with the ESP32 continuously rebooting for this reason.

As per my understanding, the issue occurs in a code that sits outside of my firmware (but I might be wrong).

What's puzzling me is that I get no log from my fw: it sounds like the flash has been erased.

The full report is as follows:

```
Rebooting...
ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46

 

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1044
load:0x40078000,len:10124
load:0x40080400,len:5828
entry 0x400806a8
***ERROR*** A stack overflow in task IDLE1 has been detected.
abort() was called at PC 0x40095ba8 on core 1
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Unhandled debug exception)
Debug exception reason: Stack canary watchpoint triggered (IDLE1)

 
ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000

 
Backtrace: 0x40093963:0x3ffbcb60 0x40095956:0x3ffbcb70 0x40095ad5:0x3ffbcc40 0x40095db9:0x3ffbcc60 0x40090fbe:0x3ffbcc80 0x40095915:0x3ffbcd40 0x40095b91:0x3ffbcd60 0x40095ba8:0x3ffbcd80 0x40097831:0x3ffbcda0 0x400994d4:0x3ffbcdc0 0x4009948a:0xa5a5a5a5
```

What's strange enough, it is I can flash it with no problems, and therefore the product runs smoothly, no problem at all again (but for how long?).

Does the error come from my code? What would be the path to get better understanding of the situation?

Any clue make my day!

Comment: Have you changed `CONFIG_FREERTOS_IDLE_TASK_STACKSIZE` so it's significantly below the default value of 1536?

Comment: What is the [Exception Decoder](https://github.com/me-no-dev/EspExceptionDecoder) output shown?

Comment: Is this just Arduino code or you are using freeRTOS?

Comment: I am using (Free)RTOS, yup

Comment: @Tarmo, nope, no modification.

Comment: The idle thread is probably not the culprit. My best guess is that something else is writing into stack area of the idle thread and you're seeing the damage after it's been done. For starters, set `COMPILER_STACK_CHECK_MODE` (menuconfig options _Compiler options -> Stack smashing protection mode_) and `HEAP_CORRUPTION_DETECTION` (_Component config -> Heap memory debugging_) to their highest settings. This greatly improves the probability of catching stack and heap overflows. But your program could just as easily be doing some bad memory accesses, which happen to land in idle thread's stack.